# PHP replace values from text area

Tags: php

I have a text area which is the body of an email message.

```
$body = 'Congrats,&#10;&#10;Line 2&#10;&#10;Line 3';
$new = str_replace('&#10;','<br />', $body)
```

I am trying to replace all instances of `&#10;` which is a linebreak in the text area field but it doesnt appear to be working.

The end result needs to generate an HTML email with `<br />`'s but in the text area, I dont want it to show html.

Comment: Sam's solution is correct http://ideone.com/HKSWOo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`str_replace()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) can take an array of search/replace values.  Try replacing other types of new lines:

```
str_replace(array("\n", "\r", '&#10;'), '<br />', $body);
```

Note the double quotes around `\n` and `\r`.

Comment: My mistake, thats what I had meant to type which is what I have tried. Any reason that wouldnt work ?